# Is it possible to split and assign a string in a single statement?

Tags: python

Can a string be split and some of the words be assigned to a tuple?

For instance:

```
a = "Jack and Jill went up the hill"
(user1, user2) = a.split().pick(1,3) # picks 1 and 3 element in the list.
```

Is such a one liner possible? If so what is the syntax.

Comment: Do you mean you need to keep the `a` variable around after splitting?

Comment: I do not mean to keep the variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to get fancy, you could use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the operand’s `__getitem__()` method. If multiple items are specified, returns a tuple of lookup values.

Example:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> pick = itemgetter(0, 2)
>>> pick("Jack and Jill went up the hill".split())
('Jack', 'Jill')
```

Or as a one-liner (w/o the import):

```
>>> user1, user2 = itemgetter(0, 2)("Jack and Jill went up the hill".split())
```

Comment: Nice (and taught to me something I didn't know too)! Still, with the import statement is not a one-liner... but two! ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this

```
a = "Jack and Jill went up the hill"
user1, _, user2, _ = a.split(" ", 3)
```

where `_` means that we don't care of the value, and `split(" ", 3)` split the string in 4 segments.

Comment: Ingenius... It doesn't scale well if you only want the 1024th element in your list though! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather do this in two lines, but here's a one-liner:

`user1, user2 = [token for (i, token) in enumerate(a.split()) if i in (0, 2)]`

Here's what I would do instead (just for readability and less chance of introducing bugs if needs to be changed in the future).

```
tokens = a.split()
user1 = tokens[0]
user2 = tokens[2]
```

Comment: That's basically my answer... 2 minutes after my post. :(

Comment: Why the frown? You won the race :)

Answer (score 2):

Slicing supports a step parameter

```
a = "Jack and Jill went up the hill"
(user1 , user2) = a.split()[0:4:2] #picks 1 and 3 element in the list
```

but while it's possible to write funky oneliners in Python for sure it's not the best language for that kind of exercise.

Comment: This only works if the elements to pick are at regular intervals, doesn't it?

Comment: If all one want are 2 elkements, they will be at a "regular interval" :-)

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick:

`user1, user2 = a.split()[0::2][:2]`

Pick the first two elements of the sequence counting from 2 in 2.

Answer (score 1):

The first that comes to my mind is:

```
>>> a = "Jack and Jill went up the hill"
>>> [e for n, e in enumerate(a.split()) if n in (0, 2)]
['Jack', 'Jill']
```

In case you wonder: [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) generates tuples with a progressive number as first element and an element of the enumerated iterable as second.

**EDIT:** As said in the comments by @kindall, the final step would be:

```
>>> user1, user2 = [e for n, e in enumerate(a.split()) if n in (0, 2)]
>>> user1
'Jack'
>>> user2
'Jill'
```

but I chose not to do the assignment just to keep the example more to the point (sorry if this confused somebody).

Comment: That's a list comprehension. He wants a tuple. (I suppose this can be addressed with a simple cast, though...)

Comment: To connect the dots for the asker: `user1, user2 = (e for n, e in enumerate(a.split()) if n in (0, 2))` (No, he didn't ask for a tuple, multiple assignment works with any sequence, even a generator expression.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can first name the `text.split()` expression in order to then use its parts within the same line and create the `(user1, user2)` tuple:

```
# text = 'Jack and Jill went up the hill'
_, (user1, user2) = (parts := text.split()), (parts[0], parts[2])
# (user1, user2) = ('Jack', 'Jill')
```